# How to convert struct in vb from c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, type-conversion

How to write this code in vb

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public static implicit operator Point(POINT point)
        {
            return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
        }
    }
```

i already try this but it's not working

```vb
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure POINT
    Public X As Integer
    Public Y As Integer

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(point As POINT) As Point
        Return New Point(point.X, point.Y)
    End Operator
End Structure
```

i get this two errors:

```
Error   1   Conversion operators cannot convert from a type to the same type.   
Error   2   Type 'MousePosition.Form1.POINT' has no constructors.
```

Is it possible to inherit struct in it self in vb?

Comment: VB is case insensitive for once, you have to give arguments and types either different names or different namespaces

Answer (score 4):

Note that in VB you have no case-sensitive code.

So POINT and Point are the same type.

You have to rename your struct to PointStruct for example.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is basically correct, but you are having a namespace conflict.  The structure is called `POINT`, but there is already a type by that same name in the `System.Drawing` namespace.  In C#, the type names are case-sensitive, so there is no conflict, but in VB.NET, the types are not case sensitive, so it doesn't know which one you mean.  The easiest thing to do would be to rename the class to something else, like this:

```vb
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> 
Public Structure ApiPoint
    Public X As Integer
    Public Y As Integer

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(point As ApiPoint) As Point
        Return New Point(point.X, point.Y)
    End Operator
End Structure
```

However, you can make it work with that name, if you really want to.  You'll just need to explicitly specify the full namespace each time you need to differentiate between the two, for instance:

```vb
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> 
Public Structure POINT
    Public X As Integer
    Public Y As Integer

    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(point As POINT) As System.Drawing.Point
        Return New System.Drawing.Point(point.X, point.Y)
    End Operator
End Structure
```